# Adding sonar in Gazebo and Ros

Tags: ros, gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wanna do a simulation for my project relating collision avoidance. I want to use sonar to do simulation in gazebo + ros. How can I add a sonar sensor to my gazebo for simulation need ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/362576/adding-sonar-in-gazebo-and-ros/) by [jenanaputra](https://answers.ros.org/users/58305/jenanaputra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2020-09-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @jenanaputra,

To add a (sonar) sensor to a model, you just need to attach the sensor link to you main model link and instantiate the sonar plugin to produce readings. `hector_sensors_description`package have already implemented a sonar sensor model with its own plugin, you can check [here](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_models/blob/groovy-devel/hector_sensors_description/urdf/sonar_sensor.urdf.xacro). If you have doubts about Xacro or URDF you can check [this](http://wiki.ros.org/xacro) and [this](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf) links

Wih that Xacro macro you can instantiate the sonar sensor and attach it to the model providing the proper `parent` link name. E.g.: `base_link`. Once attached when you launch the simulation you will be able to see it working. If you have doubts about sensor or plugin on Gazebo you can check this [link](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins) and [this](https://sir.upc.edu/projects/rostutorials/9-gazebo_sensors_tutorial/index.html).

Hope this helps you.

Regards.

---

Originally posted by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) with karma: 1695 on 2020-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1